# Neo4j: It possible to set nodes color programmatically?

Tags: neo4j

As mentioned, I wonder whether there is a command to assign a random color to nodes? I am using the free community version of neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot do this inside of Neo4j. It is really a front-end task. There are multiple free front-end tools for personal use (including ours). that offer functionality to style nodes, also based on property values.